# Get the difference between a list and JSON output in python

Tags: python

I am trying to get the difference between the elements of a list and the output of a JSON data in python.

I googled and found out some answers, but none of them seem to be applicable in my scenario.

My code is

```
my_new_user_list = json_data.get('0')
print(my_new_user_list)
my_old_user_list = ['user1', 'user2', 'joe', 'doe', 'foo'] 
diff_list = list(set(my_old_user_list) - set(my_new_user_list))
```

The output of `json_data` is `{'0': "['anonymous', 'joe', 'foo']"}`

The output of `json_data.get('0')` is `['anonymous', 'joe', 'foo']`

When i try getting the difference it does not actually get the difference between the 2 lists, it just prints the contents of `my_old_user_list`.

If `get('0')` is returning a list of values , then why is my script not printing the difference between the 2 lists.

Comment: You are trying to compare between list and string as you mention json data is "`['anonymous', 'joe', 'foo']"` is a string, not a list

Answer (score 1):

Well, as in your dictionary, it looks like it's a string, so gotta do `ast.literal_eval`, so instead of:

```
my_new_user_list = json_data.get('0')
```

Do:

```
import ast
my_new_user_list = ast.literal_eval(json_data.get('0'))
```

Comment: json.loads(json_data.get('0')) gives error as ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1), the 2nd approach using ast.literal_eval works though

Answer (score 1):

Your list in `json_data.get('0')` is not a list, but is a string

```
In [24]: json_data = {'0': "['anonymous', 'joe', 'foo']"}                                                                                                                                               

In [25]: type(json_data.get('0'))                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[25]: str

In [26]: set(json_data.get('0'))                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[26]: {' ', "'", ',', '[', ']', 'a', 'e', 'f', 'j', 'm', 'n', 'o', 's', 'u', 'y'}

In [27]: set(['user1', 'user2', 'joe', 'doe', 'foo'])                                                                                                                                                   
Out[27]: {'doe', 'foo', 'joe', 'user1', 'user2'}
```

Hence when you take a set difference between this and `my_old_user_list`, you see the old list, since there are no common elements between the two lists.

One suggestion is to define json_data with a list in the correct way by doing `json_data = {'0': ['anonymous', 'joe', 'foo']}` like so.
Note that this suggestion won't work if you are getting the data from somewhere

```
#Define value as a list
json_data = {'0': ['anonymous', 'joe', 'foo']}

my_new_user_list = json_data.get('0')

my_old_user_list = ['user1', 'user2', 'joe', 'doe', 'foo']
diff_list = list(set(my_old_user_list) - set(my_new_user_list))
print(diff_list)
```

The output will be

```
['user1', 'user2', 'doe']
```

Another approach is to use `ast.literal_eval` to parse the inner string to a list
(Note that `json.loads` won't work since you have single quotes in your string, which will break json parsing)
This suggestion should work if you are getting the data from somewhere

```
import ast

json_data = {'0': "['anonymous', 'joe', 'foo']"}

#Use ast.literal_eval to evaluate inner string as a list
my_new_user_list = ast.literal_eval(json_data.get('0'))

my_old_user_list = ['user1', 'user2', 'joe', 'doe', 'foo']
diff_list = list(set(my_old_user_list) - set(my_new_user_list))
print(diff_list)
```

Comment: Just asking what happens if he is getting this data from somewhere, not creating it... otherwise a question of how to do X, you would just do `print(desired output)`...

Comment: Yes, was about to add the `ast.literal_eval` part as you were commenting @U9-Forward :)

Comment: yes,i am getting this json_data from a web page via rest API

Comment: Okay, for that you can use the `ast.literal_eval` as per my last update to the question @PDoe :) Please check

Answer (score 0):

`json_data = {"0": "['anonymous', 'joe', 'foo']"}` clearly shows that your dictionary json_data contains the value `"['anonymous', 'joe', 'foo']"` as a string. Youcan try the following to resolve your issue.
Following is the working code with example provided in your question:

```
from ast import literal_eval

my_new_user_list = json_data.get('0')

print(type(my_new_user_list))

custom_user_list = literal_eval(json_data.get('0'))

print(type(custom_user_list))

my_old_user_list = ['user1', 'user2', 'joe', 'doe', 'foo'] 

diff_list = list(set(my_old_user_list) - set(custom_user_list))
```

I printed the types of the variable from your code and the code that I added. 
I hope I solved your issue.

Comment: the page did not show your answer when I was posting mine.